# Hibernate and Spring sessionFactory null and db not created

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I get some problem while trying to integrate Spring with Hibernate.
From the log it seems the tables and the database is created, but I can't find the database file and while inspecting the sessionFactory I get nullpointer exception, and I can't really understand what's going on.

These are my configuration files:

- web.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Fantacalcio</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ```

  - spring-mvc-servlet.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.controller"/>
```

- spring-database.xml

  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

  ```
  <!-- Hibernate ..................................... -->
  <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
  </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </beans:bean>


  <!-- Miei Bean ...................................... --> 

  <beans:bean id="utenteDao"
      class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.dao.UtenteDaoImpl"> 
  </beans:bean>
  ```

In my BaseDaoImpl I have the following code:

```
@Repository
public class BaseDaoImpl<T> implements BaseDao<T> {

//  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
//          .getLogger(BaseDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
```

The log generates these messages, resulting in null sessionFactory and no db file generated:

```
18/06/2015 11:20:49 - DEBUG - (StatisticsInitiator.java:110) - Statistics initialized [enabled=true]
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (SessionFactoryImpl.java:1339) - HHH000031: Closing
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (ActiveManagementCoordinator.java:149) - The mbean com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource,identityToken=2saucp9a1nmzsq198qnlq|1bdc6b2 was not found in the registry, so could not be unregistered.
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (ActiveManagementCoordinator.java:97) - C3P0Registry mbean unregistered.
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1022) - Preparing to destroy resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@9be45
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:616) - Preparing to destroy PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@9be45
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:477) - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@1bdc6b2 has been closed. 
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG STACK TRACE for PoolBackedDataSource.close().
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.close(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.close(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:489)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources.destroy(DataSources.java:372)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources.destroy(DataSources.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.stop(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.stopService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$2.sessionFactoryClosed(Configuration.java:1924)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryClosed(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1376)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.destroy(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:900)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5687)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1580)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (NewPooledConnection.java:646) - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@9be45 closed by a client.
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG -- CLOSE BY CLIENT STACK TRACE
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:646)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeMaybeCheckedOut(NewPooledConnection.java:259)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:619)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1024)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1049)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1010)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1260)
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:627) - Successfully destroyed PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@9be45
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1027) - Successfully destroyed resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@9be45
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (BasicResourcePool.java:1022) - Preparing to destroy resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@532db4
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:616) - Preparing to destroy PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@532db4
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl.java:308) - Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
18/06/2015 11:20:54 - DEBUG - (AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:406) - Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
```

If someone could review my xml code formatting I would appreciate, as It doesn't show properly.

EDIT: This is UtenteDaoImpl class, it does nothing as it inherits stuff from BaseDao.

```
@Repository
public class UtenteDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<Utente> implements UtenteDao{

}
```

Comment: how do you know sessionFactory is null.. the log doesn't say that

Comment: Inspecting the variable in debug.

Comment: what do you intend to do with generic in this class? this may cause the problem, you can make this class abstract let your dao class inherit this class and specify this Type. you may post your `UtenteDaoImpl`

Comment: I edited the main post adding the UtenteDaoImpl class

Comment: Please don't ask the same question in a different format. Also I suggest a read of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks on how to post code samples (I edited your original question but I doubt anyone is willing to keep maintaining editing your questions).

Comment: Using annotations and expecting them to work isn't going to do. You have to either add `<context:component-scan />` or `<context:annotation-config />` to enable annotation processing.

Comment: In my spring-servlet-xml file i have the `<context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio" />` line.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `sessionFactory` to `protected`.

```
@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

may be useful for you and solve your problem spring and hibernate both are combination this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.WordOfTheDay" />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="false" />
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/Messages" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3000" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.WordOfTheDay"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://127.11.115.2:3306/spiritualthesurus?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        p:username="admin2BXQEV1" p:password="8PcKcsgLWUMR" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000000" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```